# regular expression for username with ^[a-z0-9_-]{3-20}$

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this `^[a-z0-9_-]{3-20}$` regex for validating usernames..

my requirements

- it should be between 3-20
- it should not have special chars except hyphen and underscore
- it should start with alphabet

what is problem with this regex

- it checks for 3-20 but it also returns true when string have special chars between 3-20
- it works (return false {what is expected}) when special chars between 1-3 but it fails(return true {what is not expected}) when special chars between 3-20...

I am using yii framework and default rule match pattern...
is it yii fault ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use this:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]{2,19}$/i
```

You must use a `,` to write a range in curly brackets quantifiers. I have put an only  letter character class at first to follow your specifications (begin with a letter), thus I decrement the quantifier to `{2,19}`

I assumed you allow uppercase letters and i add an `i` modifier, but you can remove it if you only allow lowercase letters.

Note that you can write this regex like that:

```
/^[a-z][\w-]{2,19}$/i
```

since `\w` stand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`